# FireBreath and ICE38

Tags: c++, wix, firebreath

I have started to get ICE38 (Component installs to user profile. It must use a registry key under HKCU as its KeyPath, not a file.) error when building my firebreath plugin.
This the file that causes it:

```
<w:Fragment>
    <w:DirectoryRef Id="INSTALLDIR" />
</w:Fragment>
<w:Fragment>
    <w:ComponentGroup Id="PluginDLLGroup">
        <w:Component Id="cmp53DB29233E32657DBB1B18A8A6AC46CF" Guid="{28E01B1F-714F-1111-B021-111111837CAA}" Directory="INSTALLDIR">
            <w:File Id="fil5103252FF582E67B8ED35C6633BD4B7B" Source="$(var.BINSRC)\npiPlugin.dll" />
        </w:Component>
    </w:ComponentGroup>
</w:Fragment>
```

the problem is that this file looks different when I build the previous code version. It has numerous TypeLib, App, Class, Interface and RegistryValue entries.
 I have compared build environments generated by FireBreath for working and not working commits and they look identical (besides generated GUID for VS stuff). But after I build the solutions they produce different npiPlugin_auto.wixobj and npiPlugin_auto.wxs files. There were no changes made to cmake or wix files in the broken commit, so it seems the only thing that could cause this is the source code.
So, is it possible that such behavior was cause by source code changes and how can I track these changes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This file indicates that heat was unable to harvest any of the registration data from the plugin. Usually that happens because a DLL is needed to load the plugin and is unavailable when the installer is built.

You can copy the needed DLL to the output directory in a POST_BUILD command in order to fix this.

```
add_custom_command(TARGET ${PROJECT_NAME} POST_BUILD
    COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E copy "${DLLFILE_PATH}" "${FB_BIN_DIR}/${PLUGIN_NAME}/${CMAKE_CFG_INTDIR}/"
)
```

This is an untested example; DLLFILE_PATH would need to be set to the path of your DLL file that is needed. This will ensure that it is copied into location before the installer is built.

Comment: yeah, I just located the code causing this. it uses libusb (lib+dll). what is the right way to resolve this? should I mention dll file somehow in the config?

Comment: this is very inconvenient, instead of giving a message about failed reference or reg info it waits till the very last moment to show message that has almost zero useful information

Comment: Add a post-build step in your cmake to copy the file to the output location.  I added an example to my answer.

I can't do anything about how inconvenient it is... heat doesn't tell us anything useful that I know of.

Comment: it worked on one PC, but I get this error on the other (I checked the file's copied properly): heat.exe : warning HEAT5150 : Could not harvest data from a file that was expected to be a SelfReg DLL: Release\npiPlugin.dll. Unable to load file: npiPlugin.dll, error: 127. Is there a way to get more info from this?

Comment: Use Dependency Walker to get more information about why a DLL won't load. (google it)

Comment: totally forgot about it. yeah, I was so obsessed with libusb issue, that forgot to check everything else. the problem was in OpenPrinter2 function that was missing in winspool.drv on windows xp machine. with OpenPrinter everything works like a charm. thanks!

Comment: unfortunately, this doesn't work. unless dll file is in system32/syswow64 folder I still get this error.

Comment: Make sure the file is being copied to the correct place.  My target folder may be incorrect above.  The file needs to be in the same dir as the resulting DLL file.

Comment: it seems the problem is the 64bit plugin dll. heat.exe just can't extract any info from it, no matter where to put required dlls.

Comment: oh, yes.  heat doesn't work with 64 bit COM dlls. I figured it was 32 bit because SysWOW64 is for 32 bit stuff... (System Windows on Windows 64)